# Phaser3 framework javascript: current anims index

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In phaser 3 framework, what syntax do I use  to check the current frame index?

I want to make a hit area appear only when the player's sprite sheet reaches a certain index(the index displaying the motion of 'attack'). I want to accomplish this through detecting its current frame index.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need some more help or could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is found.
//hitbox solution: https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.52.0/Phaser.Animations.Events.ANIMATION_COMPLETE_KEY

```
//hitboxB listener
    gameState.playerB.on('animationstart-kill', function () {
      console.log("finish kill <3")
      gameState.hitBoxB.x = gameState.playerB.flipX ? gameState.playerB.x + 120 : gameState.playerB.x - 120;
      gameState.hitBoxB.y = gameState.playerB.y;
      // gameState.hitBoxB.visible = true;

    })
    gameState.playerB.on('animationcomplete-kill', function () {
      console.log("kill <3")
      gameState.hitBoxB.x =0 ;
      gameState.hitBoxB.y = 0;
      // gameState.hitBoxB.visible = false;
      
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, great solution, to use the key specific event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sprite events like: `Phaser.Animations.Events.ANIMATION_UPDATE`, [details in official phaser documenation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Animations.Events.html#event:ANIMATION_REPEAT__anchor)

```
    player.on(Phaser.Animations.Events.ANIMATION_UPDATE, function (anim, frame, gameObject, frameKey) {
       // Here you can check for the specific-frame
       if(frameKey == "show_hit_area_frame"){
           // ... show hitarea
       }

       // alternatively: with the index of the frame
       if(frame.index == 7){
           // ... show hitarea
       }
    });
```

In this selected Event, you can also check the current frame, for other properties of the frame object ([details in official  documenation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Animations.AnimationFrame.html)), if you don't know/have the specific framekey/index.